# Can Any one Describe a Basic CRUD Operation in Magento Front Side

Tags: magento-1.9, crud

I want to Know what is the process of ADD Update Delete in Magento from front side. so can any one help with code.

Comment: Your description of problem is a little bit... modest. Can you extend your question?

Comment: No this is not duplicate it is front side crud operation and that was backside means admin side crud operation @DouglasRadburn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a Long Research i found this full module.

**Here Namespace is Crud and Module name is Pro**

**First you want to Create Module File.**

This file is under etc folder
Path :- app\etc\modules\Crud_Pro.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Crud_Pro>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Crud_Pro>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2.:- Create config.xml file in local.
Path :- app\code\local\Crud\Pro\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Crud_Pro>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </Crud_Pro>
    </modules>  
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <pro>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Crud_Pro</module>
                    <frontName>pro</frontName>
                </args>
            </pro>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <pro module="pro">
                <title>pro</title>
                <sort_order>80</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="pro">
                        <title>childs</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>pro/adminhtml_pro</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </pro>
        </menu> 
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <pro>
                    <file>pro.xml</file>
                </pro>
            </updates>
        </layout>       
    </adminhtml> 

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <pro>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Crud_Pro</module>
                    <frontName>pro</frontName>
                </args>
            </pro>
        </routers>   
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <pro>
                    <file>pro.xml</file>
                </pro>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>    
    <global>    
        <blocks>
            <pro>
                <class>Crud_Pro_Block</class>
            </pro>
        </blocks>       

        <models>
            <pro>
                <class>Crud_Pro_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>pro_resource</resourceModel>
            </pro>
            <pro_resource>
                <class>Crud_Pro_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <pro>
                        <table>pro</table>
                    </pro>  

                </entities>
            </pro_resource>
        </models>       
        <resources>
            <pro_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Crud_Pro</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </pro_setup>
            <pro_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </pro_write>
            <pro_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </pro_read>
        </resources>    
        <helpers>
            <pro>
                <class>Crud_Pro_Helper</class>
            </pro>
        </helpers>      
    </global>
</config>
```

Step 3 :- Create Controller file
Path:-app\code\local\Crud\Pro\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Crud_Pro_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {       
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout(); 
    }
    public function saveAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        //print_r($_FILES['filename']['name']);  // name che etle image nu name levu che jo image ni type levi hoy to name ni jagya e type lakhvanu
        //exit;


        $filename = date("dmYhisa").".jpg";
        $contact = Mage::getModel('pro/pro');

        if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '')
        {
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS. 'test' ;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],$path."/". $filename);

            $contact->setData('filename',$filename);
        }

        $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');  // post thi database ma thi data lese (name) e form nu use karelu che and getdata ma database ma name nakhse
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        $rollno = $this->getRequest()->getPost('rollno');
        $gender = $this->getRequest()->getPost('gender');
        $status = $this->getRequest()->getPost('status');




        $contact->setData('stdname',$name);
        $contact->setData('email',$email);
        $contact->setData('rollno',$rollno);
        $contact->setData('gender',$gender);
        $contact->setData('status',$status);




        $contact->save();       
        $this->_redirect('pro/index/index');
    }

    public function deletedataAction()
    {

            $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

            $model2  = Mage::getModel('pro/pro')->load($id);

            $model2->delete();
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function editDataAction()
    {

        $this->loadLayout();        
        $this->renderLayout();

    }   

    public function editAction()
    {

        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');      
        $model  = Mage::getModel('pro/pro')->load($id);
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();  // form no data laya and ema apdo data set karava exit niche badhu lakhyu che



        $filename = date("dmYhisa").".jpg";
        $contact = Mage::getModel('pro/pro');

        if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '')
        {
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS. 'test' ;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],$path."/". $filename);

            $model->setData('filename',$filename);
        }



        $model->setData('stdname',$data['name']);
        $model->setData('email',$data['Email']);
        $model->setData('rollno',$data['Roll']);
        $model->setData('gender',$data['gender']);
        $model->setData('status',$data['status']);
        $model->save();
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');   
    }   
}
```

Step 4:- Now Come To Design Part.
Path:-app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\pro.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <pro_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="pro/pro" name="template_file" template="pro/pro.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </pro_index_index>
    <pro_index_editdata>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="pro/pro" name="template_file" template="pro/edit.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </pro_index_editdata>
</layout>
```

Step 5. Create Template File Assign by layout in which there are two types of form 1.save data form 2.edit data form

app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\pro\pro.phtml

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('pro/index/save'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Student intion:</legend>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" minlength="3" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
    <br>
    Roll No.:<br>
    <input type="number" name="rollno" min="1" placeholder="Enter Roll No." required>
    <br><br>

    <br>
    gender:<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <br>

        <label for="filename"><?php echo $this->__('File1') ?></label><br />
        <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" /><br/>
    <br/>
 status:<br>
 <select name="status">
 <option value="0">Enable</option>
 <option value="1">Disable</option>
 </select>

    <br>    

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>




<?php

$collection = Mage::getModel('pro/pro')->getCollection()->setOrder('rollno', 'DESC');



?>
<div id="table_id">
      <table width="80%" border="1px" style="text-align:center">
<?php
foreach($collection as $collect)
{
    //if($collect->getStatus() == 1)
    {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td>
                <?php echo $collect->getstd_id(); ?>
        </td>   
        <td>
                <?php echo $collect->getStdname(); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
                <?php echo $collect->getEmail(); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
                <?php echo $collect->getRollno(); ?>
        </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $collect->getCountry(); ?>
        </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $collect->getGender(); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
                <?php $v  = Mage::getBaseUrl("media")."test/".$collect->getFilename();?>
<?php// echo $v; ?>             
                <img src='<?php echo $v; ?>' height=50px width= 50px/>
        </td>
        <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'pro/index/deletedata?id='.$collect->getstd_id() ?>">
                <?php echo $this->__('DELETE'); ?></a>
        </td>
        <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'pro/index/editData?id='.$collect->getstd_id() ?>">
                <?php echo $this->__('EDIT'); ?></a>
        </td>


    </tr>


<?php 
    }
}

?>
</table>
</div>
```

Create Edit form file
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\pro\edit.phtml

```
<?php


    $models = Mage::getModel('pro/pro')->getCollection();
    $edit = Mage::getModel('pro/pro')->load($_GET['id']);
    echo "<pre/>";
    print_r($edit->getData());

?>



    <form  method="post" name="item_form"  id="item_form" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'pro/index/edit' ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >           
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $edit->getstd_id(); ?>" />

        <label for="title"><?php echo $this->__('Stdname:- ') ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $edit->getStdname(); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />

        <label for="title"><?php echo $this->__('Email Id:- ') ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" value="<?php echo $edit->getEmail(); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />

        <label for="title"><?php echo $this->__('Rollno:- ') ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="Roll" name="Roll" value="<?php echo $edit->getRollno(); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />


        gender:<br>

        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php echo ("male" == $edit->getGender()) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>> Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php echo ("male" != $edit->getGender()) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>> Female<br>
        <br>


        <label for="title"><?php echo $this->__('filename:- ') ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="filename" name="filename" value="<?php echo $edit->getRollno(); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />



        status:<br>
        <select name="status">              
        <option value='1' <?php echo (1 == $edit->getStatus()) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Disable</option>
        <option value='0' <?php echo (0 == $edit->getStatus()) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Enable</option>
        </select>

        <?php

        echo '<img id=output src='.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'test/'.$edit->getFilename().' width="50px" height"50px"/>'

        ?>

<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" name="filename">

<script>
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>

        <button type="submit" title="Update" name="submit" >Update</button>

    </form>
```

**Create Block file for front end**
app\code\local\Crud\Pro\Block\Pro.php

```
class Crud_Pro_Block_Pro extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

Create Helper file
app\code\local\Crud\Pro\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php

class Crud_Pro_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Now we create database so we have to create sql files here
app\code\local\Crud\Pro\sql\pro_setup\mysql4-install-0.3.0.php

```
    <?php

    $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->run("

    -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('pro')};
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('pro')} (
      `std_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `stdname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `rollno` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `gender` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`std_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        ");



    $installer->endSetup();
```

Next Update Database with version which connected to config file also.

app\code\local\Crud\Pro\sql\pro_setup\mysql4-upgrade-0.3.0-0.4.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('pro'),//table name
    'status',      //column name
    'varchar(255) NOT NULL'  //datatype definition
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

Now We Create Model
Path:-app\code\local\Crud\Pro\Model\Pro.php

```
<?php

    class Crud_Pro_Model_Pro extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    {

        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('pro/pro');
        }
    }
```

2.Path:- app\code\local\Crud\Pro\Model\Resource\Pro.php

```
<?php
class Crud_Pro_Model_Resource_Pro extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{   
    protected function _construct()
    {      
        $this->_init('pro/pro','std_id');
    }

}
```

Now to Fetch collection of our database create collection file

app\code\local\Crud\Pro\Model\Resource\Pro\Collection.php

```
<?php
class Crud_Pro_Model_Resource_Pro_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{   
    protected function _construct()
    {      
        $this->_init('pro/pro');
    }

}
```

Comment: @inrsaurabh this is for Magento 1. ;)

Comment: Can you make it for magento 2?